# "Bean name is ambiguous" CDI discovering Beans no longer supposed to be active?

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, cdi, javabeans

I'm getting the Ambigious bean-Error at the bottom when executing my Web-App with Netbeans 8.2 and Glassfish 5 using JavaEE 8. CDI is discovering the same Bean from an older version of the project I'm no longer working on, showing me the .xhtml-File from the current project, but it uses discovers the class of the same name in a different project to fill in the values for the unified expression language-fields.

This causes the conflict, since there somehow is an old bean named Foo laying around.

```
@Named
//@Named("foo")
@RequestScoped
public class Foo implements Serializable { ...
```

Renaming the Bean resolves the conflict, but my index.xhtml wont discover the right bean anymore.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        Test: #{foo2.fieldName}  //if bean is named Foo2
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Renaming the class and the references to it within the index.xthml causes the fields to be empty.

```
Schwerwiegend:   Exception while loading the app
Schwerwiegend:   Undeployment failed for context /Movie
Schwerwiegend:   Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001414: Bean name is ambiguous. Name foo resolves to beans: [Managed Bean [class NEWDIR.Foo] with qualifiers [@Default @Any @Named], Managed Bean [class SOMEODLDDIR.Foo] with qualifiers [@Default @Any @Named]]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why would that previous project be visible to this one?

Comment: Dirty cache somewhere (Glassfish or Netbeans). Rinse and repeat.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I have no idea, however the path clearly prooves this.

Comment: @BalusC Any idea on how I can clear it? restarting doesn't fix it.

Comment: try a search engine. Lots of info there on deleting/cleaning projects in netbeans and/or glassfish